# Group by a multiple select request from different tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

so I made this :

```
select  (
    SELECT COUNT (*) 
    from TXN_TOTO 
    WHERE (CO1 = '1L' OR CO1 = '1') AND OP1 in('P3', 'R1')
    ) as A,
     (
    SELECT COUNT (*) 
    from TXN_TITI 
    WHERE (CO1 = '1L' OR CO1 = '1') AND OP1 in('P3', 'R1') AND STAT = 6
    ) as B,
     (
    SELECT COUNT (*) 
    from T_TITI tti inner join T_TATA ttdi
    ON tti.ID_DINT = ttdi.ID_DINT
    WHERE (CO1 = '1L' AND OP1 in('01', '04', 'Z8')) OR  (CO1 = '1' AND OP1 in('P3', 'R1'))  AND COM = 'O'
    ) as C
FROM DUAL;
```

I get result who look like this :

```
A | B | C
----------
7 | 1 | 9
```

Both TXN_TOTO and TXN_TITI table have a 'cent' column, I'd like to filter on that in order to get

```
CENT | A | B | C
----------------
  0  | 2 | 0 | 0
  1  | 2 | 1 | 4
  2  | 3 | 0 | 5
```

Since I getting my data from 2 different tables I really don't see how to do it.

Thanks.

## EDIT : as requested here are example data and result

```
TXN_TOTO

ID_DINT | CO1 | OP1 | DID_CENT
------------------------------
    1      2L    Z3     088
    2      1L    1      089
    3      1     P3     155
    4      1L    Z3     155
    5      1L    1      077
    6      1     P3     077
    7      1L    Z3     077
    8      1L    1      077
    9      1     P3     022

TXN_TITI

ID_DINT | CO1 | OP1 | DID_CENT |STAT
------------------------------------
    1      2L    Z3     088      6
    2      1L    1      089      6
    3      1     P3     155      6
    4      1L    Z3     155      6
    5      1L    1      077      6
    6      1     P3     077      6
    7      1L    Z3     077      6
    8      1L    Z8     077      6
    9      1     R1     022      5

TXN_TATA

ID_DINT | COM |
---------------
    1      O   
    2      O   
    3      O   
    4      O   
    5      N   
    6      O   
    7      O   
    8      O  
    9      O

Expected results :

DID_CENT | A | B | C    
   155     1   1   0
   077     1   1   1
   022     1   0   0
```

A is only computed from TXN_TOTO
B is only computed from TXN_TITI, only difference is the stat column
C is a join of TITI and TATA, you need to have a O in TATA

Comment: It would make things clearer, if you provided some sample data (of the original tables)  with your expected results.

Comment: ok, working on it

Comment: what are values A,B and C?? please make clear..

Comment: I don't see why this is not clear. A is a count of 1lP3 1LR1 1P3 1R1 in the table TXN_TOTO. (where 1 or 1L is CO1 and R1 or P3 is OP1)
As stated in the request.

Comment: @sliders_alpha - "it is not clear" because you (still) haven't stated your requirement. Posting a query that does NOT do what you need does not substitute for that. (Not even posting a query that DOES do what you need would substitute for STATING the requirement). Even now with all the added detail it is not clear when a row should be counted as cent = 0, cent = 1 or cent = 2. What in the input data classifies "cent" according to 0, 1 or 2?

Comment: Cent is not counted, this has been cleared up in the edit with "expected results', in the column CENT of the result you get the CENT number which is in TXN_TITI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select coalesce(A.DID_CENT,B.DID_CENT,C.DID_CENT) DID_CENT,
       nvl(sum(A.cnt),0) A, nvl(sum(B.cnt),0) B, nvl(sum(C.cnt),0) C
 from
  (
  SELECT DID_CENT, COUNT (*) cnt
    from TXN_TOTO 
    WHERE (CO1 = '1L' OR CO1 = '1') AND OP1 in('P3', 'R1')
    GROUP BY DID_CENT
   ) A
  FULL JOIN
  (
   SELECT DID_CENT, COUNT (*) cnt
     from TXN_TITI 
    WHERE (CO1 = '1L' OR CO1 = '1') AND OP1 in('P3', 'R1') AND STAT = 6
    GROUP BY DID_CENT
  ) B ON A.DID_CENT=B.DID_CENT
  FULL JOIN
  (
    SELECT DID_CENT, COUNT (*) cnt
    from TXN_TITI tti inner join TXN_TATA ttdi
    ON tti.ID_DINT = ttdi.ID_DINT
    WHERE (CO1 = '1L' AND OP1 in('01', '04', 'Z8')) OR  (CO1 = '1' AND OP1 in('P3', 'R1'))
    GROUP BY DID_CENT
  ) C  ON B.DID_CENT=C.DID_CENT
GROUP BY coalesce(A.DID_CENT,B.DID_CENT,C.DID_CENT)
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

this is because CENT data has different values according to your A,B,C.

Dual table cant get more than one row so it is not possible to write such a sql.
Instead,

use

```
count(*) over(partition by CENT)
```

Comment: yes I know, this is what I want to get. on line per CENT in the response not only one line where every CENT is summed.